# Windows batch - delete a hidden file

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I have the following script to clean my Visual Studio 2010 solution directory:

```
@echo off
FOR /D /R %%X IN (debug,release,bin,obj,ipch) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
del /S /F *.suo
del /S /F *.user 
del /S /F *.ncb
del /S /F *.sbr
del /S /F *.log
echo Solution clean.
```

It works like a charm exept for the `suo` files - they are hidden and this script doesn't delete them.

Could you help me upgrade the script to delete the suo file too?

Kindest regards, e.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
del /S /F /AH *.suo
```

the `/AH` switch (as specified in `del /?` turns on deletion of hidden files.

Answer (score 6):

```
del /ah
```

deletes hidden files, but

```
del /a
```

deletes hidden and system and read-only files too.